# Changing color of sphere with time (processing)

Tags: java, 3d, processing

I am a new coder on processing, because of this reason please be gentle.
Normally my code is more longer and complex but I wrote a simple code for you, which I can adapt on my code:

```
int speed = 1;
int x, z = 50;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  lights();
  translate(x, height/2, z);
  fill(255,0,0);
  sphere(25);

  if (x > width -50)
    noLoop();

  x += speed;
}
```

So, like you see, sphere starts with color of red and it reaches end of the window. I want to change it's color from red to white and it should take 30 sec. to reach end of the window. However I don't know how. If you help me I will be happy. 
Note: I tried lerpColor function but didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math is the secret. Is often is.

There are a couple things you'll need to keep track of to accomplish this: the time it takes to cross the screen (you said 30 seconds), the speed of the sphere, the speed at which the color changes.

Before we start, I suggest that you use `float` for your variables which are positions and speeds. Integers will do the job, but at some point when you want precision you may regret not using floats or a similar type.

There are 2 ways to deal with changes over time: you can calculate time and draw what needs to be drawn where it's supposed to be, or calculate how many frames will be drawn in a certain amount of time and move things accordingly. The first technique has the advantage of being able to draw things where they are supposed to be even if the system is laggy (Processing will lower the framerate if it's not able to respect it), while the second is often easier to work with. We'll go with the framerate technique, as this is not supposed to be complicated and because most programs won't need so much resource that it'll lower the framerate.

The framerate, in Processing, is also the rate at which the main loop (the `draw()` loop) run. So we'll choose a framerate which will let us calculate the speed of the sphere and the speed at which the color change. The rest is just watching it move.

Here's your example, but modified so it works approximately as you told:

```
float speed;
float x, z = 50;
float greenBlueStrength = 0;
float colorFadeRate = 1;
int fadeTimeInFrames;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);
  frameRate(60); // 60 is the default framerate per second
  // so 30 seconds == (30*60) == 1800 frames
  // so you must have the speed to match
  fadeTimeInFrames = 60 * 30;
  speed = (width - 50) / (float)fadeTimeInFrames;
  colorFadeRate = 255 / (float)fadeTimeInFrames;
  println(colorFadeRate);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  textSize(30);
  text((millis()/1000) + " s. // color: " + (int)greenBlueStrength, 20, 50);
  // this is just to keep track of changes while they happen

  noStroke();
  lights();
  translate(x, height/2, z);
  fill(255, greenBlueStrength, greenBlueStrength);
  sphere(25);

  if (x > width -50) {
    noLoop();
  } // no actual change, but use brackets anyway, it's easier to read

  // updating what needs to be updated
  x += speed;
  greenBlueStrength += colorFadeRate;
}
```

I'll hang around so don't hesitate if you have questions.

Have fun!

Comment: First off all thank you so much for your help and suppor @Iaancelot. I tried your code and it helps a lot. So, I would like to ask one more question. If the shpere color would fill(255,153,8); and size (1200,800,P3D) also the time 120 sec. what would change?

Comment: Yes, it would. I hardcoded `fadeTimeInFrames = 60 * 30;` to keep track of how many frames the "animation" will last, while in fact the equation would be `seconds * framerate == total amount of frames`. So you would have to change this number. For the distance, I already used the `width` property, which would update automatically. That's it for speed and frame count.

Comment: For the color, though, it would be different. I would suggest to use the `color` structure, if you start using specific colors. Or you could use Safir's strategy and keep different values for R, G and B. What I did different was mostly to keep them as float so I can gradually add to them (and they convert to integer when I use them for a color, so the trailing numbers are good only to keep a more precise track of the speed at which it changes).

Comment: Ultimately it's all simple math, more precisely fractions: your have to divide the wanted change by the number of frames that you'll fill. If you want to move X pixels in Y frames, the speed at which your object move is X/Y pixels per frame. Same thing goes for any other change that you can quantify, in this case like the change in color.

Comment: Thank you so much @Iaancelot I totally understood whay you are saying and it helps me a lot even for the other my problems. You are a hero! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that would work:

```
int r=255,b=255,g=255;

...

void draw(){
...

  int percent=x/width*100;
  fill(r,b*percent,g*percent)
  sphere(25)

...
}
```

so the sphere would be red only on the left of the screen and white on the right

Comment: first of all thank you for help and support. I've tried your idea but it didn't change the sphere color. Maybe, it looks like more birght with your code. However I want to change color step by step. Red to White.

Comment: for it to work as i meant it, make it like that: int percent=x/width   so that 255*percent fall between 0 and 255 (and not 25500 :x).    if you just want to make a step, you could do it like if(x<width/2) ->fill(255,0,0) else ->fill(255,255,255)      (in the draw())